# how user identity in other entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this model

```
public class Teacher 
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last name { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }

}
```

how to make this entitey conected to the identity for  every teacher can only updat his teacher profile or delete

Comment: Right and what is the question

Comment: I using templet of mvc then users for creating  Teacher  you have sign up  in application than you can caret Teacher  profile but how to make every user registered can only have authorization to update or delete his profile

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your question is as follow:

**After a teacher signed up to my website, how can I allow the teacher to only edit his/her profile?**

Answer:

1. When teacher logs in to your application, capture the ID of the teacher.
2. When opening your teacher "profile" page, pass/send through the ID of the teacher.
3. Only display the contents related to that ID of the teacher.
4. When the teacher save their edited profile, do an update against that ID of the teacher only.

Since you are using web, you can save, for instance, the username and ID of the teacher in, for example, the following ways:

1. Session variable
2. Cookie (Not safe, any hacker could impersonate a teacher)

I hope this will clear some of the issues you facing.

Comment: thnak but in login page I had used the temple of microsoft for sigin up & login

Comment: Are you connected to any database?